# formula array replacement not working without debug mode

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an array formula which is above 255 characters. I have broken it into smaller texts that are lesser than 255 chars. Now the problem I'm facing is with that replacement is not happening as intended. However, when I debug the lines, replacements happen perfectly fine.

```
Sub FreezeCellsWith_NA_Tgt(Optional ByVal skillType As String = Constants.ALL)
 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
   
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
   
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim textToFind As String, dq As String, sq As String, amp As String
    Dim fullFormula As String, splitFormulaStr1 As String, splitFormulaStr2 As String
    Dim firstTxtFoundCellAddr As String
    Dim lngMatches As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim LastTechnicalSkillsRow As Long, LastFunctionalSkillsRow As Long, LastBehaviouralSkillsRow As Long
    Dim txtFoundRange As Range, iCell As Range
           
    dq = Chr(34) ' double quote as a variable
    amp = Chr(38) ' ampersand as a variable
    sq = Chr(39) ' apostrophe or single quote as variable
 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
   
        LastColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastTechnicalSkillsRow = .Range("A3:A250").Find("% TECHNICAL GAP", , xlValues).Offset(-3, 0).Row
        LastFunctionalSkillsRow = .Range("A3:A250").Find("% FUNCTIONAL GAP", , xlValues).Offset(-3, 0).Row
        LastBehaviouralSkillsRow = .Range("A3:A250").Find("% BEHAVIOURAL GAP", , xlValues).Offset(-3, 0).Row
       
        Set searchRange = .Range("A4:" & Col_Letter(LastColumn) & 4)
        textToFind = "Target"
       
        Set txtFoundRange = searchRange.Find(What:=textToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
       
        If Not txtFoundRange Is Nothing Then
            firstTxtFoundCellAddr = txtFoundRange.address
            Do
                Debug.Print txtFoundRange.address
                If skillType = Constants.ALL Or skillType = Constants.TECHNICAL Then
                    If LastTechnicalSkillsRow >= 6 Then
                        For Each iCell In .Range(Col_Letter(txtFoundRange.Column) & 6 & ":" & Col_Letter(txtFoundRange.Column) & LastTechnicalSkillsRow)
                                Debug.Print "[SM] Unfreezing range : " & iCell.address & ":" & iCell.Offset(0, 2).address
                               
                                fullFormula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP($A" & iCell.Row & ", TXT1, TXT2, FALSE), SkillLevel!$B$3:$C$7, 2, FALSE), ""NA"")"
                                splitFormulaStr1 = "INDIRECT(""'"" & INDEX(SkillSheetNames, MATCH(1, --(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""'"" & SkillSheetNames & ""'!$B$2:$B$100""), $A" & iCell.Row & ")>0), 0)) & ""'!$B$2:$F$100"")"
                                splitFormulaStr2 = "MATCH(" & Col_Letter(iCell.Column) & "$3, INDIRECT(""'"" & INDEX(SkillSheetNames, MATCH(1, --(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""'"" & SkillSheetNames & ""'!$B$2:$B$100""), $A" & iCell.Row & ")>0), 0)) & ""'!$B$1:$Z$1""), 0)"
 
                                .Range(iCell.address).FormulaArray = fullFormula
                                .Range(iCell.address).Replace "TXT1", splitFormulaStr1, xlPart
                                .Range(iCell.address).Replace "TXT2", splitFormulaStr2, xlPart
                            End If
                        Next iCell
                    End If
                End If
                Set txtFoundRange = searchRange.Find(What:=textToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, after:=txtFoundRange)
            Loop While Not txtFoundRange Is Nothing And txtFoundRange.address <> firstTxtFoundCellAddr
        End If
    End With
   
    Calculate
   
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

The formula created is fine, however when macro is triggered from the button, replacement doesn't happen. When I try to debug the code at the point, replacement happens fine. I'm unable to understand the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue to my problem lies in the protection of the sheet. I had to unprotect the sheet before making the replacements after which replacements worked pretty fine as expected.